# Layerslider - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: jquery, slideshow, joomla3.2

I'm trying to implement layerslider on my new website (joomla 3.2).

http://www.webcilento.com/site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=3&Itemid=128

In chrome console I see the following error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

[edit] after adding the missing ',' the error is

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ready'**

I'm loading JQUERY via jQuery Easy Plugin.

Here is the complete code: where am I wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').layerSlider({
        skinsPath: 'http://www.webcilento.com/site/layerslider/skins/',
        skin: 'defaultskin' --> added the ,
        width: '1280px',
        height: '720px',
        responsive: true,
        responsiveUnder: 0,
        sublayerContainer: 0,
        autoStart: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        firstLayer: 1,
        animateFirstLayer: true,
        randomSlideshow: false,
        twoWaySlideshow: true,
        loops: 0,
        forceLoopNum: true,
        autoPlayVideos: false,
        autoPauseSlideshow: 'auto',
        youtubePreview: 'maxresdefault.jpg',
        keybNav: true,
        imgPreload: false,
        touchNav: true
    });
});
// ]]>
```

Comment: you have a missing `,` after `skin: 'defaultskin'`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: use a proper IDE for development so that this kind of syntax error can be easily detected

Comment: Just added the ',' but that was non the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a wrong .js ordering in head.
I solved re-ordering jquery and layerslider .js in the head section of my website.